# Php Text to image Autofit?

Tags: php

I create the code for the text to image in php and save to png/jpeg.
But the problem is the that the some times the text is so long and it does not cover the full area.and it will out of the box and text is missing.
the code is like this

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);
    $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
    imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);
    $text = 'Testing...';
    $font = 'arial.ttf';
    imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);
    imagejpeg($im,'name.jpg');
    imagedestroy($im);
    ?>
```

this code works fine nut when i add the long text it will out of the box.is there anyother solution for this to autofit the text into the box?

Comment: I did this before, but the code is somewhere at home. If there is no one who can answer I'll fetch it in the evening. Edit: BTW is your width fixed? or could it be variable? and what do you expect if the text is to long?

Comment: the box width is fixed.i want to adjust text into the box

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I made a small function (not tested yet)

```
function getTextFactor($font, $text, $size, $angle, $width, $height)
{
    //if the size are zero don't execute any further, it's not necessary
    if($width == 0 || $height == 0) throw new ArgumentException("$width or $height could not be zero!");

    //get the text size
    $box = imagettfbbox($size, $angle, $font, $text);

    $minX = min(array($box[0],$box[2],$box[4],$box[6]));
    $maxX = max(array($box[0],$box[2],$box[4],$box[6]));

    $minY = min(array($box[1],$box[3],$box[5],$box[7]));
    $maxY = max(array($box[1],$box[3],$box[5],$box[7]));

    $factorX = 1;
    if($tmpWdith = ($maxX - $minX) > $width)
    {
        $factorX = $tmpWidth / $width;
    }

    $factorY = 1;
    if($tmpHeight = ($maxY - $minY) > $height)
    {
        $factorY = $tmpHeight / $height;
    }

    return min(array($factorX, $factorY));
}
```

Where you will get the factor to resize the font in the image.

you can use this as follows in your script:

```
$width = 400;
$height = 30;
$textSize = 20;
$textAngle = 0;
$text = 'Testing...';
$font = 'arial.ttf';

$im = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, $width-1, $height-1, $white); //why exactly do you subtract 1?

$factor = getTextFactor($font, $text, $textSize, $textAngle, $width, $height);
imagettftext($im, $textSize*$factor, $textAngle, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

imagejpeg($im, 'name.jpg');
imagedestroy($im);
```

Please note, at the moment the above factor function doesn't use padding or margins for the text.

if you want to have the width, use the following function:

```
function getTextBox($font, $text, $size, $angle)
{
    $box = imagettfbbox($size, $angle, $font, $text);

    $minX = min(array($box[0],$box[2],$box[4],$box[6]));
    $maxX = max(array($box[0],$box[2],$box[4],$box[6]));

    $minY = min(array($box[1],$box[3],$box[5],$box[7]));
    $maxY = max(array($box[1],$box[3],$box[5],$box[7]));

    return array("width" => abs($maxX - $minX), "height" => abs($maxY - $minY));
}
```

and just create the image with the size you get.

Comment: Thanks so much..But if the box size is variable  and font size is fixed.is it possible to create the box according to the text length??

Comment: @Heena: was this answer useful to you? It is customary here to upvote/accept, to thank and reward the poster for their answer.